# Dropdown not updating Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to `Knockout.js` and I find a code section of a dropdown which is never getting updated. Below is the code :

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-9">
    <select class="bs-select" data-width="100px" data-bind="value: measurement">
        <option>Gallons</option>
        <option>Pounds</option>
        <option>Days</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var viewModel = function (data) {
var self = this;
self.measurement = ko.observable(measurement);
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

Whatever option I select from the dropdown, it shows up as Gallons. If I change the order and put Days or Pounds first, it remains days or pounds even if I change it.
Let me know if I am missing something.

EDIT 1: I tried adding value to the options list. Does not change the issue.

```
 <option value="Pounds">Pounds</option>                                                                            
 <option value="Days">Days</option>                                                                            
 <option value="Gallons">Gallons</option>
```

Comment: Well, the question is missing all your JS. Not sure what else you're missing!

Comment: You're missing `value` attributes in your `<option>` tags.

Comment: @Steji Why is there a need for JS for the basic dropdown to function?

Comment: @user3297291 Check my latest edit, does not help.

Comment: You don't show enough code for us to help; the only thing we can do is point out "something you are missing". The only thing I can be certain of given the code you provide, is that it cannot work *without* `value` attributes. I never said adding them will fix it. Long story short: show us your accompanying javascript code.

Comment: In your view model function, you appear to be ignoring its `data` parameter. Also, you say "Whatever option I select from the dropdown, it shows up as Gallons." In your HTML, you don't indicate *where* you are expecting the selected value to show up.

Comment: @DavidRR I meant whatever value I select in the dropdown, the first value is displayed on the screen. So even if I select Pounds from the dropdown, the display will still remain Gallons after selecting a different value from the dropdown.

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean by "displayed on the screen"? Do you mean the dropdown itself? That is, if you select `Days` in the dropdown, the dropdown immediately goes back to `Gallons`?

Comment: @DavidRR Yes. That is what I mean. Hence I believe it is not a binding issue and more of an HTML issue.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working jsFiddle for what you seek:

https://jsfiddle.net/njbLqpmq/

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-9">
    <select class="bs-select" data-width="100px" data-bind="value: measurement">
       <option value="Pounds">Pounds</option>
       <option value="Days">Days</option>
       <option value="Gallons">Gallons</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = function (data) {
   var self = this;
   self.measurement = ko.observable();
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine. Any specific change that you have made to the code? I have the same code but does not work in my application.

Comment: Is measurement an observable, like in my answer and is the html bound?

Comment: `self.measurement = ko.observable(measurement);` what is measurement? r u looking at your console, any errors as if measurement is undeclared variable then will fall over and html wont be bound.

Comment: measurement is basically the value I am getting from the database if a value is stored. No console error and it works fine. Hence I believe my issue is with the HTML control and not the binding part.

Comment: so measurement a global variable? HTML fine as you can see by my fiddle. Can u replicate this in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

you probably need the options binding.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

here is a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/24/

```
 <select class="form-control" data-width="100px" data-bind="value: measurement, options: availablemeasurements">
    </select>
```

js

```
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.measurement= ko.observable('');
  this.availablemeasurements=ko.observable(['Pounds', 'Day', 'Gallons']);
}
```

If you don't wish to use the options binding and just use value that appears to work as well.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-width="100px" data-bind="value: measurement">
      <option>Pounds</option>
        <option>Day</option>
        <option>Gallons</option>
    </select>
```

here is the fiddle for that.

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/25/

Comment: Yeah was figuring out that was the case. Is there no way my approach can work?

Comment: This might sound scary at first, I promise it's not :)  Take a look at both bindings, `value` and `options`, the code is fairly simple: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/value.js and https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/options.js.  That way you can see what else is happening in options that a simple value binding doesn't account for.  You'll also need to refer to the `selectExtensions`: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/4391eb9b9b5d8b5b481d364f54800585215552b6/src/binding/selectExtensions.js

Comment: Long story short, you need to set the value of drop downs in a specific way.